# Install webkit or geckofx for VB

Tags: vb.net, websocket, webkit, gecko, geckofx

I need a WinForm that shows HTML like Choroe or Mozilla.  I have a problem with web sockets.
Then I use `WebBrowser` component in Visual Studio and it's not showing web socket.

How can I install a component for browser that shows web socket like Chrome V.43 or Mozilla v.38.

Comment: Why do you want to create an application just for that ? What's wrong with just opening your website ?

Comment: I don't want no one easily find out the domain address.publish this program and distribute to my client on the other hand no one know my domain address in common way(for personal reason)

Comment: Why don't you want people to find your domain address ? Is there some super secret stuff there ? If there is, just not giving the URL will not protect it, as it **will** be found by Google & co. Plus, it's super easy to find the URL called through programs like WireShark and Fiddler. If your website has sensitive information, just protect it through regular security : login/password, https, and so on.

Comment: Its sort of illegal website in my region and prefer people cant see URL easily.

Answer (score 0):

I really had hard time to solve this problem because i start programming about 6 days ago!
now should answer this question clearly.
Use "Awesomium" component, its really easy to use and support websockets. i think i use version 1.7.5.1 ,so just visit official website and download program,install it and finish :) you have awesomium.net tab in toolbox in visual studio.
Any question?